# Javascript: array1[0] = array2[0]; does this pass by value or by reference?

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, pass-by-reference

```
this.lastLocations[0] = this.locations[0];
this.locations[0].x++;
```

When this code is executed it increments both locations[0].x and lastLocations[0].x.  I want it to just change locations[0].x.  Is this because javascript is assigning the reference rather than the value?  Or is the problem somewhere else in my code?

Comment: oo got it.  still learning stack overflow mechanics and etiquette.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects in javascript are assigned by reference so both your variables are pointing at the exact same object.

So, when you do this:

```
this.lastLocations[0] = this.locations[0];
```

Then, both `this.lastLocations[0]` and `this.locations[0]` now point to the exact same object.  If you make a change to that object via either one of these variables, then that change will show via the other variable (because they both point at the exact same object).

If you want to assign a copy, then you literally have to make a copy of the object (by creating a new object and then copying over all the properties from the original to the new object) and assign that new copy.

There are numerous other posts on methods for cloning/copying an object:

[What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object)

[How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

[is it possible in Javascript to tell an object to stop having reference behavior with another object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444972/is-it-possible-in-javascript-to-tell-an-object-to-stop-having-reference-behavior/14444998#14444998)

And, some other related questions:

[Do objects pushed into an array in javascript deep or shallow copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660901/do-objects-pushed-into-an-array-in-javascript-deep-or-shallow-copy/8661088#8661088)

[Javascript by reference vs. by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value)

Comment: @SUCHANOOB - see references I added to my answer on ways to make a copy of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in JavaScript is passed and assigned **by value**.

"Objects" are not values in JavaScript. The only values in JavaScript are primitives and references (pointers to objects). So `array1[0]` is either a primitive or pointer to an object, and `array2[0]` is either a primitive or pointer to an object.

When you do `array1[0] = array2[0]`, it assigns the object pointer so that both pointers point to the same object.

Comment: Eh, not the downvoter but this is a very confusing way to explain it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: This is the *correct* way to explain it.

Comment: Well... to be fair, I didn't want to say it - but it's really not _that_ correct. There are a number of terminology inaccuracies in this answer. You should really consult the spec - namely http://es5.github.io/#x8.7 about the terminology of object values, reference and such. Pointers don't exist at all in JavaScript (no reference operator, dereference operator, pointer arithmetic and so on), JavaScript is pass by reference value.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: So what what the spec says? Description of semantics is only useful in a way that is consistent across languages. The semantics of passing and assigning in JavaScript is EXACTLY identical to Java and many other languages, where non-primitives are "references", and reference is defined as "a pointer to an object", which is consistent with how it is called in C++.